# How can an alien meet the president of the USA without attracting attention?

Tags: aliens

An alien arrives on Earth as a representative/ambassador of their government. Let's assume they arrive by some means of stealth ship and that they have no "special powers" (other than the fact that they don't need sleep, food etc) and look human.

Their government has given them instructions not to demonstrate their stealth ship or draw unnecessary attention to themselves before they have had a chance to speak to the President of the USA and give a controlled first impression.

The alien goes to the front gate of the White House and demands to speak to the president, saying he won't leave until he is given a chance to speak to him. Since he does not require sleep, food etc, he can literally stand there for days on end waiting for his request to be fulfilled.

Questions:

- What would actually happen? Would he simply be left standing there forever or would he be arrested and on what charge?
- Is there a more realistic way of trying to get a meeting with the President of the USA under these circumstances?

Comment: *"...they don't need sleep, food etc) and look human"* Presumably their human appearance is an artifice designed to make contact with humans easier, because the human body shape is a consequence of our physical requirements, including food and sleep.

Comment: Last time I walked past the White House, there was a queue doing exactly that: stay there until arrested.

Comment: Does it have to be face to face or would hacking in to presidents hotline work for first contact?

Comment: @DaveHalsall really it has to be face-to-face because of (a) more of a chance to demonstrate that you really are an alien and not just some crazy person, (b) when you are face-to-face you have more assurance that you are alone with the President (or at least as alone as you can be, plus secret service)

Comment: @Lostinfrance - yes, exactly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Donate a very large sum of money to the political party in power.**

If the president has only had one term, you can do even better by donating directly to the re-election campaign.  Then, you can discreetly make it known that you are behind said donation, and that you wish to meet with the president.  They would be **obligated to give you a token amount of face time**, at which point you could attempt to speak to them.  This would be the best moment at which to demonstrate any other advanced technology.  If that's not an option, **choose your words carefully**, lest you be taken merely as a very rich crackpot!

*(I am making the assumption that if your species has mastered the finer points of space travel, then it can also counterfeit US currency or hack our banking system without too much trouble.)*

Answer (score 7):

If the aliens are required by their government not to draw unnecessary attention to themselves then one thing they cannot do is stand in an immensely public place for days on end without sleep or food.

In 2003 the American magician David Blaine spent [44 days](http://news.bbc.co.uk/onthisday/hi/dates/stories/october/19/newsid_3700000/3700652.stm) suspended in a glass box over London, going without food for this time. It was a media sensation.

Admittedly, your alien ambassador isn't suspended in a box. But standing outside the White House for weeks would be noticed without the box, and even without the display of superhuman powers. The protester [Brian Haw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Haw) became famous for simply camping in a tent in Parliament Square for years. The whole point of doing this right outside the Houses of Parliament was to be noticed by the media. Protests take place outside the White House for the same reason.

The alien needs to make his vigil somewhere where the public won't notice him but the authorities will.

Presumably the aliens have the means to tell where, say, secret work on Black Projects is carried out - the equivalents of [Area 51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_51) that *aren't* famous. Since there really are extraterrestrials and UFOs in your universe, it's more than likely that the US government has some idea of this and a place to research the issue. If he knows of this place, the alien ambassador can probably spare himself the tedium of standing outside for ages. If he presents himself at the highly secret front door displaying detailed knowledge of what is done there he *will* be taken seriously. All he has to do to be believed completely by the base personnel is get them to take an X-ray, which given that this place actually *is* a base for research on aliens, should be easy to arrange. He won't get dissected. No one murders a peaceful emissary from a power which has already demonstrated superior technology for the trivial benefit of seeing how his insides work, particularly as he is offering to demonstrate that voluntarily.

None of this is remotely as cool as [Wingman4l7's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/31820/9207), of course. But I think taking a side in the domestic politics of primitive species is against the First Contact (Isolated Planet) Protocol & Code of Conduct.

Comment: Good point re: talking sides in politics!  I guess the alien had better ask for their donation back once they're introduced properly ;)

Comment: That, or the president ropes him in as a campaign bundler. We aren't told how well paid being an alien ambassador is. Maybe the alien would prefer to swap the role of Species X Ambassador to Earth for the much better renumerated role of US Ambassador to somewhere with nice scenery and good shopping.

Comment: Hah yes, maybe Earth is the "Alaska assignment" for aliens.

Answer (score 1):

Just wear a sandwich board that says:

> Greetings, Mr. President, from the people of [planet name here].

This won't attract any unnecessary attention, since you will be dismissed as crazy.  However, we all know that the president has access to privileged information and is aware of the existence of alien life (if not your planet in particular).  He will at least send someone to make an enquiry.

You can respond to this enquiry by providing a piece of information about alien activity the president is aware of, which will be meaningful to the president but not the messenger.

If that is not possible, just make your best plea to meet the president and wait.  You will be monitored, and it will be noticed that you don't need to eat or sleep.  This will get you a meeting.

Comment: Would not eating and sleeping get you a meeting, or would it get you a black-bag kidnapping & dissection? :/

Comment: @Wingman4l7, well, if that is what the president plans to do upon discovering you are an alien, you are kind of out of luck.

Comment: Good point; it's hard to have many bargaining chips dealing with the POTUS.  I'd be worried a triple-letter agency would notice first, and take matters into their own hands.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to persuade the president that you are who you claim to be, without persuading anyone else of this.

Since there are only about ten to twenty thousand cranks vying for his attention, this is going to be a complicated affair.

I'd say to use the stealth technology you have to place notes on the President's desk in the Oval Office (or other locations in the White House if the desk is monitored too closely).  You will definitely have their attention after doing this a few times.  Include in each note instructions which will tell the President how to demonstrate that he or she believes the claims.  When these demonstrations are forthcoming, arrange the meeting.

Your chances of being treated with anything but respect are minimal at this point:  "Mr. President, we can assume that whoever's behind this can institute regime change at will.  Ticking them off is probably a bad idea."